# How does newTempHashMap work in mapdb?

Tags: mapdb

How does newTempHashMap work in mapdb? Is it just a file-backed hash map or is there an in-memory caching layer?

Answer (score 1):

It creates file in temporary folder. File gets deleted when JVM exits.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a limitation on the number of temp hash maps that should be used in a single app? Is it ok to use about 100 maps?